# ExtJS 4.2.1 grid field with tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4.2

I'm trying to get a hover/tooltip effect for some text in an ExtJS (4.2.1) grid.
For some reason, the tooltip `span` is being occluded by the pretty much everything else.

Seems to be an issue with stacking, but I'm not sure the best way to bring the `span` in front of everything else (other rows, and the frame surrounding the grid).

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z3jj601f/

I tried using z-index to no avail.
Can anyone tell me the right way to bring the tooltip span to the absolute foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achieve this using a Ext.tip.ToolTip. As in 4.2.1 documentation you can delegate the tooltip show/hide specifying a dom selector.

In you case:

1. Add a custom class to you the cells you want the tooltip for

   ```
   columns: [{
     ...
   }, {
     text: 'Status',
     dataIndex: 'status',
     tdCls: 'my-tooltip'
   }
   ```
2. Create the tooltip with delegate

   ```
   var view = grid.getView();
   var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
     target: view.el,
     delegate: '.my-tooltip',
     trackMouse: true,
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     listeners: {
       beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
         var record = view.getRecord(Ext.get(tip.triggerElement).up('tr'));

         // Update tooltip text according to current record
         tip.update('Over record ' + record.getId());
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbb5xh74/

Comment: this helps me create a tooltip - and I very much appreciate that; but I'd still like to know, for my own understanding, why the CSS version didn't work - if anyone has more input

Comment: Probably you missed a "overflow: hidden". In fact adding "* {overflow: visible !important;}" to your css the tooltips are visible. You should search in the complex extjs DOM what's the tooltips container/s to set overflow visible.

Comment: You're right!  In fact my original Fiddle works if I set that rule on `.x-border-box`